# Typescript is finding errors where there aren't

Tags: node.js, typescript

I trying to oerfirm a save in MongoDB with Mongoose, but the code I get was not working, so I google that, I have find a working solution, but tyescript keeps telling me, that there is an error.

But the code actually works.

This is the code that is not working, but as per typescript it is ok:

```
userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: Function) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            user.password = hash;
            user.save({}, (err, doc) => callback);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the code that is working but typescriot shows me an error an I cannot compile with tsc ( I can do it with gulp build)

```
userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: Function) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            user.password = hash;
            user.save(callback);
        });
    });
});
```

Please notice the save function.
Here you have the image.
[image]

With the first option the issue is that the callback is not being fire in the save.

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sss",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example App uses TypeScript, Node.js, Express 4, MongoDB, Mongoose.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.17",
    "inversify": "^4.11.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.10",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/debug": "0.0.29",
    "@types/dotenv": "^2.0.20",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.15",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.77",
    "@types/passport": "^0.3.3",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^2.0.20",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.7",
    "gulp-yaml": "^1.0.1",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && nodemon src/index.ts",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "test": "tsc && mocha -t 30000 dist/**/*.test.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/devslaw/TypeScript-Node.js-REST-example.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Arthur Arakelyan <arthur@devslaw.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/devslaw/TypeScript-Node.js-REST-example#readme"
}
```

--- UPDATE ---

IUser

```
import {Schema, Model, Document, model} from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export interface IUserModel {
    createUser(user: IUser, callback: Function): void
    comparePassword(candidatePassword: string, hash: string, callback: Function): void
    findByEmail(email: string, callback: Function): void
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createAt: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now()
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now()
    }
});

userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: Function) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            user.password = hash;
            user.save(callback);
        });
    });
});

userSchema.static('comparePassword', (candidatePassword: string, hash: string, callback: Function) => {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
});

userSchema.static('findByEmail', (email: string, callback: Function) => {
    User.findOne({email: email}, callback);
});

export type UserModel = Model<IUser> & IUserModel & IUser;

export const User: UserModel = <UserModel>model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

The error is:

```
src/shared/models/user.ts(44,23): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, product: IUser, numAffected: number) => void'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(err: any, product: IUser, numAffected: number): void'.
```

Comment: Can you provide `IUser` interface?

Comment: You mention: "*typescript shows me an error*". What error? The `Function` type is assignable to very few other types, so I'm guessing that's the issue. If you tell us the error text we will know what type it actually ought to be.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel IUser interface added.

Comment: @CRice There you have the error description. That's the result of running tsc. But if I compile the ts file with gulp build, it works

Comment: You should change the type of your `callback` parameter to match the type in your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the error you're getting, the `user.save` method is expecting to receive a callback with the type:

```
(err: any, product: IUser, numAffected: number) => void
```

Since the `Function` type is very broad and encompases bascially any callable, there is no guarantee that something which is a `Function` will accept the parameters listed in the narrower type above.

To fix this, you should restrict your `callback` argument to be of the narrower type. This will remove the error when you pass it to `user.save`, and will make sure that whatever callback you give to `createUser` is of the right form (since currently you could pass any function to it, even if it's not of the right type).

So for your snippet, change the line:

```
userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: Function) => {
```

to

```
userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: (err: any, product: IUser, numAffected: number) => void) => {
```

So that the callback is of the more specific type.

Comment: To reduce on clutter, pull out the callback type `type UserCallback = (err: any, product: IUser, numAffected: number) => void` and `userSchema.static('createUser', (user: IUser, callback: UserCallback)...`